# Using WHERE col IN with many data OR select all rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I select many data at once like

> WHERE id IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ).

Imagine that we might have more than 10.000 Numbers inside the `IN` query. It's better to do the `select` as I'm doing it using `IN()` or just select all data and do the parse with PHP Code for the `IDs` I want?

Comment: I think that would depend on the size of the data set and how much data that is going to be returned but ignored.

Comment: Well i think most of the times, ALMOST all rows are being selected using the IN(). For example 9500 out of 10000, or 300 out of 330. Most of the times it is like this. You think it's better with PHP?

Comment: One of the reasons I asked is I know with some different versions of the software there is a hard limit to how many values you can put in an IN clause. Either way a lot depends on your setup and where it is best to put the load and yes php should be fast with removing data but mysql can also be fast.

Comment: Where does the list of IDs come from? You note in response to an answer that getting the inverse list (the ID's you don't want) would require a separate query. How do you get the list of 9,500 IDs that you *are* interested in, if not via a query?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the IN statement will include almost all possible values (90-95% based on your example numbers).  Joe W is correct that depending on your setup it could go either way and it's impossible to say for sure without testing which of those two would be faster.

However, you will eventually run in to a diminishing return on a query like that.  While one or the other will be faster than the other, neither will be fast. (by default MySQL will allow you up to max_allowed_packet for # of values, which is a lot).  A faster option would be to use where NOT IN and just list the 5-10% of values you didn't want.

Comment: but that would require to run another query, to fetch all the IDs first.

Comment: @user3393046 Just because you are running a second query doesn't mean it is going to be slower overall.

Comment: @user3393046 - How did you get that long list of ids in the first place??